# How to use button value for filter pipes in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe

I'm developing a blog site which has a menu where I need to be able filter my blogs from a blog genre that the user selects. I am currently trying to use a filter pipe and when the user picks a genre from the sub-menu the list of blogs get filtered according to the genre.

I've used a filter pipe once before with a text input field and it worked but this time I need it to filter according to the button value selected by the user and I can't get it to work.

I am trying to set the value of the searchTerm of the filter to the genre that I need to filter by when the button is clicked as below:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <ul [(ngModel)]="searchWord">
    <li>
      <button mat-button (click)="searchWord = 'Business and Economy'">Business and Economy</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button mat-button (click)="searchWord = 'Law and Social Justice'">Law and Social Justice</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button mat-button (click)="searchWord = 'Global Health'">Global Health</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button mat-button (click)="searchWord = 'Foreign Affairs'">Foreign Affairs</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<ng-container class="ng-container" *ngIf="blogs.length > 0">
  <h2>Featured Blogs</h2>
  <div class="blog-card-div" *ngFor="let blog of blogs | blogFilter:searchWord">
      <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8" id="card-div" >
```

This is my code for my filter pipe below:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { Blog } from '../blog.model';

@Pipe({
  name: 'blogFilter'
})
export class BlogFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  // first arg might need to be the string of songs
  transform(blogs: Blog[], searchTerm: any): Blog[] {
    if (!blogs || !searchTerm) {
      return blogs;
    }
    // filters applied to the song array
    return blogs.filter(blog =>
       (blog.genre.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1));
  }
}
```

Currently my filter doesn't work, am I doing something wrong or can you just not filter according to a button selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the need for two-way binding to the `ngModel` directive. Try without it

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <ul>           <!-- no use for `ngModel` here -->
    <li>
      <button mat-button (click)="searchWord = 'Business and Economy'">Business and Economy</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button mat-button (click)="searchWord = 'Law and Social Justice'">Law and Social Justice</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button mat-button (click)="searchWord = 'Global Health'">Global Health</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button mat-button (click)="searchWord = 'Foreign Affairs'">Foreign Affairs</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank you, removing that made it responsive!

Comment: You're welcome :). Would be great if you accepted the answer.